# Best jQuery slideshow plugin with pause/play/next/prev controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I've done my homework - I swear, I've been researching this for a bit.

I have found two nice options, each with its own particular problem:

Option #1: "Supersized" @ http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/
The problem is that the images become stretched to essentially become the background-image. 
I want the images to stay within a div.

Option #2: "Liferay's Rotating Banner" @ http://sandbox.thewikies.com/liferay-rotating-banner/
The problem is that this is way too HTML5-dependent.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jQuery Cycle Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) is the best.

Pause/Resume controls example:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/pause.html

Prev/Next controls example:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/after.html